# Run a service automatically in a docker container

Tags: riak, docker

I'm setting up a simple image: one that holds Riak (a NoSQL database). The image starts the Riak service with `riak start` as a CMD. Now, if I run it as a daemon with `docker run -d quintenk/riak-dev`, it does start the Riak process (I can see that in the logs). However, it closes automatically after a few seconds. If I run it using `docker run -i -t quintenk/riak-dev /bin/bash` the riak process is not started (UPDATE: see answers for an explanation for this). In fact, no services are running at all. I can start it manually using the terminal, but I would like Riak to start automatically. I figure this behavior would occur for other services as well, Riak is just an example.

So, running/restarting the container should automatically start Riak. What is the correct approach of setting this up?

---

For reference, here is the Dockerfile with which the image can be created (UPDATE: altered using the chosen answer):

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server curl 
RUN curl http://apt.basho.com/gpg/basho.apt.key | apt-key add -
RUN bash -c "echo deb http://apt.basho.com precise main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/basho.list"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install riak
RUN perl -p -i -e 's/(?<=\{http,\s\[\s\{")127\.0\.0\.1/0.0.0.0/g' /etc/riak/app.config
EXPOSE 8098 
CMD /bin/riak start && tail -F /var/log/riak/erlang.log.1
```

EDIT: -f changed to -F in CMD in accordance to sesm his remark

---

## MY OWN ANSWER

After working with Docker for some time I picked up the habit of using supervisord to tun my processes. If you would like example code for that, check out https://github.com/Krijger/docker-cookbooks. I use my supervisor image as a base for all my other images. I blogged on using supervisor [here](http://blog.trifork.com/2014/03/11/using-supervisor-with-docker-to-manage-processes-supporting-image-inheritance/).

Comment: By the way. I'm now (for development purposes) using the container by starting it, attaching to it, and then starting Riak command line.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To keep docker containers running, you need to keep a process active in the foreground.

So you could probably replace that last line in your Dockerfile with

```
CMD /bin/riak console
```

Or even

```
CMD /bin/riak start && tail -F /var/log/riak/erlang.log.1
```

Note that you can't have multiple lines of CMD statements, only the last one gets run.

Comment: I'm now using the second option. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 32):

Using tail to keep container alive is a hack. Also, note, that with `-f` option container will terminate when log rotation happens (this can be avoided by using `-F` instead).

A better solution is to use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). Take a look at this [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_riak_service/#dockerizing-a-riak-service) about running Riak in a Docker container.

Comment: That looks promising.
If you already have experience using that in combination with docker, would you care to share a short example here?

Answer (score 5):

The explanation for:

> If I run it using `docker run -i -t quintenk/riak-dev /bin/bash` the riak process is not started

is as follows. Using CMD in the Dockerfile is actually the same functionality as starting the container using `docker run {image} {command}`. As Gigablah remarked only the last CMD is used, so the one written in the Dockerfile is overwritten in this case.

By using `CMD /bin/riak start && tail -f /var/log/riak/erlang.log.1` in the Buildfile, you can start the container as a background process using `docker run -d {image}`, which works like a charm.

Comment: Similarly, I am trying to dockerize CDH. In that case, i am starting service using RUN command. It starts and exits after that RUN command. What could be the reason?

Comment: @GopsAB probably there is some kind of error that prevents the main process from (keeping) running. Check your logs or try your CMD manually by starting the container with /bin/bash and see what happens

Comment: If process crashes, tailf continues to run. Same story as @damick

Answer (score 5):

> "If I run it using docker run -i -t quintenk/riak-dev /bin/bash the riak process is not started"

It sounds like you only want to be able to monitor the log when you attach to the container. My use case is a little different in that I want commands started automatically, but I want to be able to attach to the container and be in a bash shell. I was able to solve both of our problems as follows:

In the image/container, add the commands you want automatically started to the end of the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file.

In your case just add the line `/bin/riak start && tail -F /var/log/riak/erlang.log.1`, or put `/bin/riak start` and `tail -F /var/log/riak/erlang.log.1` on separate lines depending on the functionality desired.

Now commit your changes to your container, and run it again with: `docker run -i -t quintenk/riak-dev /bin/bash`. You'll find the commands you put in the bashrc are already running as you attach.

Comment: That's actually a very nice solution :)
Note that 0.6.5 added that `docker run -a` option for supervisors compatibility. You might want to chack that out as well.

Comment: Not a good solution. What will you do if process exits, tailf will continue running, container will not exit.

Comment: @MincăDanielAndrei You're right in part. This is not a production ready solution, it's not sustainable for the reason you mention. It's best if at all possible to have the `entrypoint` or `cmd` of your image be the process you want to run itself. Often this means you need to find the `--no-daemon` option for said process to keep the container from exiting when the entrypoint backgrounds itself and exits, and to make it log to stderr/stdout.

Comment: Another option would be to use `dumb-init` , the init system for containers, as stated here https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2016/01/dumb-init-an-init-for-docker.html

Answer (score 3):

Because I want a clean way to have the process exit later I make the last command a call to the shell's **`read` which causes that process to block until I later attach to it** and hit enter.

```
arthur@macro:~/docker$ sudo docker run -d -t -i -v /raid:/raid -p 4040:4040 subsonic /bin/bash -c 'service subsonic start && read -p "waiting"'
WARNING: Docker detected local DNS server on resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4]
f27229a260c9

arthur@macro:~/docker$ sudo docker ps                                                                                                                                     
[sudo] password for arthur: 
ID                  IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED              STATUS              PORTS
35f253bdf45a        subsonic:latest     /bin/bash -c service   2 days ago          Up 2 days           4040->4040

arthur@macro:~/docker$ sudo docker attach 35f253bdf45a

arthur@macro:~/docker$ sudo docker ps                                                                                                                                     
ID                  IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
```

as you can see the container exits after you attach to it and unblock the read. 
You can of course use a more sophisticated script than `read -p` if you need to do other clean up, such as stopping services and saving logs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple trick whenever I start building a new docker container. To keep it alive, I use a ping in the entrypoint script.

So in the Dockerfile, when using debian, for instance, I make sure I can ping.
This is btw, always nice, to check what is accessible from within the container.

```
...
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y iputils-ping 
...
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

And in the entrypoint.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
...
ping 10.10.0.1 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

I use this instead of `CMD bash`, as I always wind up using a startup file.