# Docker multiple entrypoints

Tags: docker

Say I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN apt-get install -y mongod #pretend this exists

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2"]
```

The `ENTRYPOINT` command makes it so that `apache2` starts when the container starts. I want to also be able to start `mongod` when the the container starts with the command `service mongod start`. According to the [documentation](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/builder/#entrypoint) however, there must be only one `ENTRYPOINT` in a Dockerfile. What would be the correct way to do this then?

Answer (score 95):

As Jared Markell said, if you wan to launch several processes in a docker container, you have to use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). You will have to configure supervisor to tell him to launch your different processes.

I wrote about this in this [blog post](https://www.yabage.me/2014/05/19/a-deeper-look-into-dockerfiles/), but you have a really [nice article here](http://blog.trifork.com/2014/03/11/using-supervisor-with-docker-to-manage-processes-supporting-image-inheritance/) detailing how and why using supervisor in Docker.

Basically, you will want to do something like:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN apt-get install -y mongod #pretend this exists
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor # Installing supervisord

ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf 

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

And add a configuration a file supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:mongodb]
command=/etc/mongod/mongo #To adapt, I don't know how to launch your mongodb process

[program:apache2]
command=/usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND
```

---

**EDIT**: As this answer has received quite lot of upvotes, I want to precise as a warning that using Supervisor **is not** considered as a *best practice* to run several jobs. Instead, you may be interested in creating several containers for your different processes and managing them through [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).
In a nutshell, *Docker Compose* allows you to define in one file all the containers needed for your app and launch them in one single command.

Answer (score 24):

My solution is to throw individual scripts into `/opt/run/` and execute them with:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=/var/log/all

touch $LOG

for a in /opt/run/*
do
    $a >> $LOG &
done

tail -f $LOG
```

And my entry point is just the location of this script, say it's called `/opt/bin/run_all`:

```
ADD 00_sshd /opt/run/
ADD 01_nginx /opt/run/

ADD run_all /opt/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/bin/run_all"]
```

Comment: Supervisor is arguably better, since it can restart your processes if they die, has configurable logging options, can receive commands remotely over RPC, etc. Like this though

Comment: This answer is better for environments that do not have an option for installing supervisor or other similar technology. Plain and straighforward

Comment: This doesn't work well if a process dies, since it doesn't restart processes, as @twneale pointed out.  I don't see why installing Supervisor or similar lightweight process managers _inside a Docker image_ would not be an option.

Comment: Also you don't need the log file. If you like, you can just do "/my/runnable >> /dev/stdout"

Answer (score 16):

Typically, you would not do this. It is an anti-pattern because:

1. You typically have different update cycles for the two processes
2. You may want to change base filesystems for each of these processes
3. You want logging and error handling for each of these processes that are independent of each other
4. Outside of a shared network or volume, the two processes likely have no other hard dependencies

Therefore the best option is to create two separate images, and start the two containers with a compose file that handles the shared private network.

---

If you cannot follow that best practice, then you end up in a scenario like the following. The parent image contains a line:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint-parent.sh"]
```

and you want to add the following to your child image:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint-child.sh"]
```

Then the value of `ENTRYPOINT` in the resulting image is replaced with `/entrypoint-child.sh`, in other words, there is only a single value for `ENTRYPOINT`. Docker will only call a single process to start your container, though that process can spawn child processes. There are a couple techniques to extend entrypoints.

**Option A**: Call your entrypoint, and then run the parent entrypoint at the end, e.g. `/entrypoint-child.sh` could look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Running child entrypoint initialization steps here
/usr/bin/mongodb ... &

exec /entrypoint-parent.sh "$@"
```

The `exec` part is important, it replaces the current shell by the `/entrypoint-parent.sh` shell or process, which removes issues with signal handling. The result is you run the first bit of initialization in the child entrypoint, and then delegate to the original parent entrypoint. This does require that you keep track of the name of the parent entrypoint, would could change between versions of your base image. This also means you lose error handling and graceful termination on mongodb since it is run in the background. This could result in a false healthy container and data lose, neither of which I would recommend for a production environment.

**Option B**: Run the parent entrypoint in the background. This is less than ideal since you will no longer have error handling on the parent process unless you take some extra steps. At the simplest, this looks like the following in your `/entrypoint-child.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# other initialization steps

/entrypoint-parent.sh "$@" &

# potentially wait for parent to be running by polling

# run something new in the foreground, that may depend on parent processes
exec /usr/bin/mongodb ...
```

Note, the `"$@"` notation I keep using is passing through the value of `CMD` as arguments to the parent entrypoint.

**Option C**: Switch to a tool like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). I'm not a huge fan of this since it still implies running multiple daemons inside your container, and you are usually best to split that into multiple containers. You need to decide what the proper response is when a single child process keeps failing.

**Option D**: Similar to Options A and B, I often create a directory of entrypoint scripts that can be extended at different levels of the image build. The entrypoint itself is unchanged, I just add new files into a directory that gets called sequentially based on the filename. In my scenarios, these scripts are all run in the foreground, and I exec the `CMD` at the end. You can see an example of this in my [base image repo](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base), in particular the `entrypoint.d` directory and `bin/entrypointd.sh` script which includes the section:

```
# ...

for ep in /etc/entrypoint.d/*; do
  ext="${ep##*.}"
  if [ "${ext}" = "env" -a -f "${ep}" ]; then
    # source files ending in ".env"
    echo "Sourcing: ${ep}"
    set -a && . "${ep}" && set +a
  elif [ "${ext}" = "sh" -a -x "${ep}" ]; then
    # run scripts ending in ".sh"
    echo "Running: ${ep}"
    "${ep}"
  fi
done

# ...

# run command with exec to pass control
echo "Running CMD: $@"
exec "$@"
```

However, the above is more for extending the initialization steps, and not for running multiple daemons inside the container. Given the bad options and issues they each have, I hope it's clear why running two containers would be preferred in your scenario.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 11):

The simple answer is that you should not because it breaks the single responsibility principle: one container, one service. Imagine that you want to spawn additional cloud images of MongoDB because of a sudden workload - why increasing Apache2 instances as well and at a 1:1 ratio?
Instead, you should link the boxes and make them speak through TCP. See https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/ for more info.

Comment: A single service could need to run more than one daemon/process, which is the topic of this discussion. Your point makes sense if we talk about running a web server and a database, which should be in different containers, but you could be also in a situation where you need to run a Python/Ruby/Java app that makes use of a message queue watcher. Then you need to start 2 processes in that container (2 entrypoints): your app and the queue watcher.

Comment: @JoséL.Patiño not sure I understand - how would the queue watcher talk to the web app? Via TCP/IP? If that's the case, you can still run them in two different queues, and scale them independently of each other (which was my original point). If communication is through IPC/UNIX sockets/else, then it might be different.

Comment: I think what Jose was pointing out are cases where you have one service running and a small script that needs to be running as well (this is not as uncommon as we think). I just encountered this when running a server in a docker container and need to execute 'crond' to run cron in alpine. I'm sure there are many other cases.

Comment: There is a common pattern called _sidecar containers_ for these small scripts / auxiliary servers - create a new image for just that script/server, opening up ports as required to talk to main container.

Answer (score 6):

I was not able to get the usage of `&&` to work. I was able to solve this as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19872810/2971199

So in your case you could do:

```
RUN echo "/usr/sbin/apache2" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
RUN echo "/path/to/mongodb" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

You may need/want to edit your start commands.

Be careful if you run your Dockerfile more than once, you probably don't want multiple copies of commands appended to your `bash.bashrc` file. You could use `grep` and an `if` statement to make your `RUN` command idempotent.

Comment: what will happen I I try to access/attach the terminal. It will run those processes.

Answer (score 4):

You can't specify multiple entry points in a Dockerfile. To run multiple servers in the same docker container you must use a command that will be able to launch your servers. Supervisord has already been cited but I could also recommend [multirun](https://github.com/nicolas-van/multirun), a project of mine which is a lighter alternative.

Answer (score 4):

There is an answer in docker docs:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

But in short

> If you need to run more than one service within a container, you can accomplish this in a few different ways.

The first one is to run script which mange your process.

The second one is to use process manager like *supervisord*

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several ways:

- you can write a script to put on the container (`ADD`) that does all the startup commands, then put that in the `ENTRYPOINT`
- I think you can put any shell commands on the `ENTRYPOINT`, so you can do `service mongod start && /usr/sbin/apache2`

Comment: ```service mongod start && /usr/sbin/apache2``` wont monitor the 2 processes as it should.

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to run **multiple concurrent npm scripts** such as a watch script and a build script for example, check out:

[How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)