# running npm task in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to write an example of running npm tasks in parallel.  We are supposed to be able to do this with "&" for parallel and "&&" for series.

```
{
  "name": "npm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "console": "node ./npm-scripts/console.js",
    "task1": "node ./npm-scripts/task1.js",
    "task2": "node ./npm-scripts/task2.js",
    "task3": "node ./npm-scripts/task3.js",
    "parallel": "npm run task1 & npm run task2 & npm run task3",
    "series": "npm run task1 && npm run task2 && npm run task3"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "date-and-time": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to actually work.

Here is where my code is.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 but if you know NPM then you can just use the command line.

[my github parallel and series examples](https://github.com/robertdunaway/katas-npm/tree/master/004%20npm%20-%20series%20%26%20parallel/after)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Bob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run multiple NPM scripts in parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, we cannot use `&` to run tasks in parallel.

[npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) is useful in this case, IMO.

```
{
    "name": "npm",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "console": "node ./npm-scripts/console.js",
        "task1": "node ./npm-scripts/task1.js",
        "task2": "node ./npm-scripts/task2.js",
        "task3": "node ./npm-scripts/task3.js",
        "parallel": "npm-run-all --parallel task1 task2 task3",
        "series": "npm-run-all task1 task2 task3"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "date-and-time": "^0.3.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^1.5.1"
    }
}
```

We can use glob-like pattern to specify tasks:

```
        "parallel": "npm-run-all --parallel task{1,2,3}",
        "series": "npm-run-all task{1,2,3}"
```

Other solutions:

- [parallelshell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallelshell)
- [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)