# How do run watchify, browser-sync, and automatic browser refresh simultaneously using only package.json

Tags: npm, browser-sync, package.json, watchify

Is there a way to watch for code changes, and automatically reload the browser using only npm and package.json (I'm trying to avoid using Gulp et al. )  If so, can you suggest some scripts to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and ended up using the pipe operator, which runs tasks concurrently. For example:

```
cp -R css src/css && watchify src/js/main.js -o src/js/bundle.min.js | node bs.js
```

Which is essentially: copy the CSS, then run watchify and browser-sync concurrently.

From a quick skim of the link below, I think the issue is with this is will only work on Mac OS and Linux, not Windows. For that you can use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

More discussion of this here: [How can I run multiple NPM scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)