# webpack and lite-server for react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, package.json, lite-server

I built my own webpack.config.js for react development, also I use lite-server. Is it possible to put both `webpack` and `lite-server` commands to package.json like that:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "lite-server webpack"
}
```

or are there any other ways to do that?

Comment: did you try it out ? ;)

Comment: yes, works just first one

Comment: This is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run 2 commands **sequential** from package.json script you can use "anding" like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "lite-server && webpack"
}
```

It first runs command `lite-server` followed by run of `webpack` if `lite-server` did not fail.

For **concurrent** execution I would recommend https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently package.

There is also https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all but I have not tested it myself.

Comment: I tried this, but the second one waits for the first to finish, and that will never happen. Also  I tried this
`"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack && lite-server"
}`
but webpack is in watching mode, so it will never finish by itself.
Is there any other possible way to run them both at the same time just with `npm run dev`?

Comment: You could use npm packages I mention on edited post for concurrent run.