# TypeScript tsc: How to watch multiple projects at the same time?

Tags: typescript, watch, tsc

I have two `tsconfig.json`, in the root and in the `test` folder:

```
.
├── dist
│   └── file...
├── dist-test
│   └── file...
├── src
│   └── file...
├── test
│   ├── file...
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

As you can guess, files from `src` compiling into `dist` and files from `test` compiling into `dist-test` folder.

From the root, I can to run `tsc -w` or `tsc -w --project test` for watching file changes. How can I run them at the same time (inside one terminal)?

I tried to do `(tsc -w) && (tsc -w --project test)`, but not succeed. Only the first directive is being implemented and its compiled only `dist`.

**UPD**: My question is no duplicate [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30950032/1716560)
 because I work with one utility `tsc` which, I believe in this, can handle two projects at once. I do not need parallel processing with different programs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel) - not quite the same question, but the answers are identical.

Comment: @JoeClay, no this is not a duplicate, although it's relative.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to compile multiple projects in a single call to `tsc` (unless something has changed since [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3645#issuecomment-117826581)).

Answer (score -4):

your question is more a "bash" question instead of a typescript:

You're right with starting 2 instances of tsc, as much as I know you need at least one instance for each tsconfig.json.

In Your example it will start the 1st tsc in watch mode and waits till it ends, after that it'll start the 2nd tsc.

please try this:

```
(tsc -w &) && (tsc -w --project test)
```

This will start the 1st tsc in background (so you have to kill it manually if you need) and the 2nd one in front.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it `tsc -w & tsc -w --project test`, but I did not like it.

Comment: yes, sorry it's the poor man's way, all others need additional tools to control the 2 processes as one :)