# Running multiple apps at the same time?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I want to run multiple apps at the same time with angular-cli.

I've followed these steps: https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/

If I serve app0 or app1, they run without any problem.
**But my problem is, I want these apps run at the same time. Some routes should run app0, some routes should run app1.**

In package.json, I wrote this script:

```
"develop-both": "ng serve --app 0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json && ng serve --app 1 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

But this script only runs first app in **angular-cli.json**. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel. There is also pm2

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @David. I think I found the solution with your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I've found the solution for running multiple scripts with the help of David in comment section of the question.

Here is how I run multiple scripts:

```
"develop-both": "ng serve  --app 0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --port 4200 | ng serve  --app 1 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --port 4201"
```

I needed to run these apps in different ports. One of them is running in 4200, the other running in 4201.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the pipe symbol will only work on UNIX like environments to run both concurrently