# How to make npm to start both angular and node servers

Tags: node.js, angular

Is it possible to start both angular default server(port:4200) and node.js(port:8080) using npm?

**packages.json:**

```
"start":"ng serve && node server.js"
```

If I run **npm start**, only angular's server(4200) is started running but not node's server(8080).

Is there a way to make both the servers has to run on their respective ports at same time using npm.

Need someone's help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Comment: The second answer should work, replacing the `&&` with a pipe `|`

Comment: Have you tried opening a second terminal window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside of your package.json you can add

```
"start": "ng serve --open | nodemon node/",
```

Keep in mind that it is relative to your package.json location , so in the above example node is a subdirectory inside my angular project.  This will also open a browser for you.  If you don't want the browser to open just remove the --open

Full example

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve --open | nodemon node/",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
```

},

You can use gulp of course as the other answer suggests

Comment: Your welcome @I.George , we have all been there and need that little extra help.   Best of luck on your project

Comment: How I can do it if angular project is a subdirectory inside node project
@Alex Mackinnon

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have control over startup scripts, maybe it is a better approach to use a tool directly designed for that. (Workflow automation)

May I recommend [gulp.js](https://gulpjs.com/): with it, you can define scripts that will run in a sequence or paralell.

A very basic example:

```
gulp.task('node-server-start', function (cb) {
  spawn('node', ['server.js'], {stdio: 'inherit'}) 
});
gulp.task('ng-serve', function (cb) {
  spawn('ng', ['serve'], {stdio: 'inherit'}) 
});
gulp.task('start', ['ng-serve', 'node-server-start'], function () {
});
```

And you just start it wih `gulp start`