# How do I use nodemon for both eslint and babel

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, eslint, nodemon

I have some start scripts that look like this:

```
"nodemonBabel": "nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node",
"nodemonLint": "nodemon src/index.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'"
```

I use `npm run nodemonBabel` in cli to watch my code with `nodemon` and trigger Babel to transpile it on code change. I also use `npm run nodemonLint` to watch with `nodemon` while triggering `eslint` on code change.

How do I combine both scripts into a single line? I.e, watch my code with nodemon, lint and  transpile with Babel from a single script which I don't have to rerun for every change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is run two scripts concurrently, see here: [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel/30950298#30950298)

Use a package called [concurrently](http://npmjs.org/package/concurrently).

`npm i concurrently --save-dev`

Then setup your `npm run dev` task as so:

```
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run nodemonBabel\" \"npm run nodemonLint\""
```