# nodemon npm sequential start scripts

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I have scripts block in my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js config/referenceBooks/girlsTypeInsert.js && src/app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

but after executing my first script girlsTypeInsert.js

```
var GirlType = require("../../models/girlType");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/posts');
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error"));
db.once("open", function(callback){
    console.log("Connection Succeeded");
});
GirlType.count({}, function(err, c) {
    if (c > 4) {
        console.log('Girls types already in db');
        db.close();
    } else {
        GirlType.insertMany([{ name: "Shere"},
            { name: "Kaori Nazuka"},
            { name: "Main"},
            { name: "Reone"},
            { name: "Asakawa"}], function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Girls types inserted in db");
            db.close();
        });
    }
});
```

nodemon give me message

> [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

what I need to change for starting my next script app.js?

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30950298/6877699)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace this

> config/referenceBooks/girlsTypeInsert.js && src/app.js"

to

> --exec \"config/referenceBooks/girlsTypeInsert.js && src/app.js\""