# Yarn: Run two packages concurrently in Windows

Tags: reactjs, windows, yarnpkg

I need to run two yarn packages in Windows Command, which contain two react package modules.
This works succesfully in Mac Ubuntu.

```
yarn dev -p "\"+(app-one|app-two)\""
```

However, it does not work in Windows.

I tried referencing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64937839/15435022, however it does not work. What is the proper command to run two packages simulataneously in Windows?

**Package Json:**

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "yarn compile:packages && node concurrently-dev.js",
```

**Command Line Tests:**

```
yarn dev -p "\"+(app-one|app-two)\""
yarn dev -p "app-one" "app-two"
yarn dev -p \"app-one"\ \"app-two"\
yarn dev -p "app-one" & yarn dev -p "app-one"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use the [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) package. Simply install it using `yarn add concurrently` and update your package.json like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "concurrently \"yarn compile:packages\" \"node concurrently-dev.js\"",
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
yarn start dev -p "app-one" "app-two"
```