# How to start BE and FE with one npm script command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-scripts

I got a node.js and React.js project, separated in different directory.

```
Project
 - BE
 - FE
```

when start my project for local development, i have to type 3 command

- redis-server
- cd BE && npm run dev
- cd FE && npm run dev

I wonder how could i combine these command as a single command to make my life easier ?

All these command is will hang until we abort them
I can't just `redis-server && cd BE && npm run dev .....`

Comment: I have a project setup like this and I created a tmux script to do all that in one command (open 3 terminal windows, do all these commands and more)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently)

```
concurrently "command1 arg" "command2 arg"
```