# Run two npm commands concurrently

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, json-server

I've setup `json-server` and runs successfully on `port-3000` then run `npm start` it runs on other port `3001`.

But I want to run both concurrently. I tried with [Concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) but didn't work.

When I execute this command :

```
$ concurrently "npm start" "json-server --watch ./topPanelData.json"
```

Error message:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved issue with these steps:

1. Create `json-server.json` with the following key to run a server on a different port.

   `{ 
   "port": 4000
   }`
2. Update start script in `package.json`

   `"start": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"json-server ./topPanelData.json\""`
3. simply run `$ npm start` It'll concurrently execute both on the different port

   **json-server:** http://localhost:4000/topPanelData

   **React app:** http://localhost:3000/

Comment: just remember people to download concurrently and save it as a dev dependency: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the process running in port `3000` with

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:3000)
```

Where

```
lsof -t -i:3000
```

finds the process running on port 3000 and kill kills that process

If you're only getting this error on using `concurrently`, that means it's trying to run both processes in port `3000`

Try changing your start script in `package.json`

```
"start": "export PORT=3006 react-scripts start"
```

With some experimentation, you'll be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an  **.env** file in your porject directory, parallel to .json file and add below line .

```
PORT=3001
```

This solution worked for me .