# node-sass watch multiple folders

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

I am trying to set up an NPM script that will watch for changes to .scss files in multiple directories and compile them to separate directories.

This is my current set up:

```
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "npm run bcon-watch && npm run root-watch",
    "root-watch": "node-sass -wr --source-map true --output-style compact css/sass/ -o css/",
    "bcon-watch": "node-sass -wr --source-map true --output-style compact bcon/css/sass/ -o bcon/css/"
  },
```

However this only runs the first script and watches that directory (root-watch), is it possible to watch multiple folders this way? if not what should I look into to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and tried several solutions, but the only one working for me was this
[How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

> Use a package called concurrently.
>
> npm i concurrently --save-dev
>
> Then setup your npm run dev task as so:
>
> ```
> "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run start-watch\" \"npm run wp-server\""
> ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29954184)