# React scripts not starting the server alongside another script

Tags: css, reactjs, react-scripts, tailwind-css

I followed [this](https://medium.com/@mikeeeeeeey/create-react-app-tailwind-css-feat-postcss-631d9e33ba8c) tutorial in order to add Tailwind to existing CRA app, css is generated but it doesn't start the server with this script:

`"watch:css": "postcss src/styles/index.css -o src/index.css -w"`

Here is the log:

```
  > app@0.1.0 start C:\Users\*\Documents\projects\app\client
[1] > npm run watch:css & react-scripts start
[1]
[1]
[1] > app@0.1.0 watch:css C:\Users\*\Documents\projects\app\client
[1] > postcss src/styles/index.css -o src/index.css -w
```

It never calls the other part of the script.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel

Comment: Thank you, it works with `npm-run-all` :)