# Run many nodejs servers in one command

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

I have few Nodejs servers, they are small servers and each one of them is stored in a separate folder. And all the folders are stored in one root folder. Every time i want to run the servers i have to go through each one of them and type

`nodemon *name*`.

This is becoming tiresome, especially that the number of servers is growing. is there any tool or a script i could use to run all the servers in one command?? 
Basically, how can i run all the servers in one command or a script?

Comment: You can write a shell script to run the commands you run manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NPM. Write this in package.json :

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server1.js | nodemon server2.js | nodemon server3.js"
  }
}
```

Then you only need to execute `npm start`.

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Comment: Thanks. Another question, how can i run each one of them in a separate terminal?

Comment: Is this Windows portable?

Answer (score 1):

[PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) is a great answer for this.

`pm2 start app.js -i 4` (or `max` will take up all available cores)

You also get great benefits such as automatic restarts, log aggregation and load balancing.

Comment: ah, good idea, I use PM2 in prod, but I didn't think about this solution in a dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

If you use Linux

```
#!/bin/bash 

pm2 start << Path to User Server>> 
pm2 start << Path to User Server>> 

pm2 logs
```

You can save

```
pm2 save 

pm2 list 

pm2 stop
```