# Npm script to run both child directory folders?

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-scripts

How do I write a script in my Parent Folder's package.json file so that when I run `npm install` it installs the node modules in each folder and `npm start` will go to each folder and run `npm start`

The Frontend and Backend folder both use `npm start` to start up and I want to somehow do the same in the parent folder to simultaneously start both

This is the file structure:

```
ParentFolder
├── package.json .     <--- npm install && npm start scripts
├── FrontEnd
│   ├── /node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   └── index.js
├── Backend
│   ├── /node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── routes.js
│   └── server.js.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing in two directories is easy with `find`

```
find ./*/* -maxdepth 1 -name package.json -execdir npm install \;
```

This looks in each directory for a package.json and executes `npm install`;

`npm start` becomes a bit harder. At least on Windows using Cygwin, I wanted to do:

```
npm --prefix ./FrontEnd start ./FrontEnd & npm --prefix ./Backend start ./Backend
```

But it wasn't actually running in the background like I expected and FrontEnd was the only one that actually started. Depending on your start script this could work for you.

Possible solutions for this could be [`concurrently`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30950298/10559113) or [`npm-run-all -p`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all).

Comment: That didn't work, it just made 2 folders called Backend and Frontend in the same parent directory. Sorry if I wasn't clear but what I intended to was that the start scripts will navigate to Frontend folder and run `npm install` then navigate to the Backend folder and run `npm install`

Comment: Ah thanks. I think I have a solution. Just running it locally to make sure it works.

Comment: Edited with more info