# Running Eslint and Nextjs development server at the same time

Tags: npm, eslint, next.js, npm-scripts

I want to integrate Eslint in my Nextjs application and prefer to run Eslint simultaneously with the development server. I have two scripts, namely `server` and `lint` and want to run them at the same time. I tried to implement it via `dev` script, but the development server seems not to be reloading on file changes in this implementation. Is there any way to run the two simultaneously?

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run server && npm run lint",
    "server": "next -p 7777"
    "lint": "esw --fix components/**/*.js lib/**/*.js pages/**/*js"
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Comment: @RobC, I actually tried to run them as `npm run server && npm run lint`, but it didn't work as `nextjs` seemed to be not reloading on file changes.

Comment: Did you try using [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) as suggested in the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel#answer-30950298)?