# Running 2 commands in npm script(nodemon && sass --watch)

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, npm-scripts

I have a package.json file looks like this.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/app.js -e js,hbs ",
    "scss": "sass --watch public/scss:public/css",
    "both": "nodemon src/app.js -e js,hbs && sass --watch public/scss:public/css",
    "both2" : "npm run dev && npm run scss"
  },
```

I wonder why I cannot run these 2 commands:

"both": "nodemon src/app.js -e js,hbs && sass --watch public/scss:public/css"

by

```
npm run both
```

When I try to run it, only the first command is working.

Github repository is below, just in case you need some testing.

https://github.com/tuanphanfi/weather-app-nodejs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a package called [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

```
npm install concurrently
```

Then you can make a script called `both`

```
"both": "concurrently \"nodemon src/app.js -e js,hbs\" \"sass --watch public/scss:public/css\""
```

See [javascript - How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Comment: I marked your reply as the answer.
It works pretty well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On UNIX-like systems you can just use **`&`** instead of **`&&`** to chain your commands. **`&` is used for parallel script execution** whereas **`&&` causes a sequential execution**, meaning the 2nd one starts only when the 1st has finished successfully.

```
cmd1 &  cmd2 & ...     # parallel 
cmd1 && cmd2 && ...    # sequential
```

Whereas on Windows-Systems prepending each of your commands with `start` and chaining them with `&&` seems to do the trick...

```
start cmd1 && start cmd2 && start ...
```

For cross-platform solutions, see f. i. either [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently), like Namko suggests, or [npm-run-all](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all). Those solve other problems as well, that might or might not occur when using the above platform-specific solutions (problems like weired/mixed terminal-outputs, multiple terminals/windows, bad control over process/thread-termination etc.) ...