# Problem with npm start (error : spawn cmd ENOENT)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, git-bash

I have a problem with my application. Because before when I created an application it worked, but now, it shows me this error and I do not know why and the things I have to do to fix it.

Do you have any idea to help me ? (This is a reactJS app).

I checked some stackoverflow topics but everywhere I checked, it was not really an answer that worked.

```
events.js:180
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', 'http://localhost:3000/' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fix-react-module@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fix-react-module@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-16T09_33_39_111Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I tried to change environment variables but I'm not sure what to add in PATH

Comment: 1. `npm cache clean --force`, 2. Delete `node_modules` folder, 3. `npm install` 4. `npm start`. Should fix the errors, works for me. Just to be safe delete `package-lock.json` too before doing `npm install`

Comment: I will try, but every time I create a new application, this error comes up again

Comment: with : npx create-react-app app-example -> cd app-example -> npm start (it worked before)

Comment: something is running on the same port probably, try changing, in MAC try, netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3000

Comment: clean the npm cache, should fix the errors. Not related to ports.

Comment: do you mean the 3000 host?

Comment: I will try to clean but I do not want the error to happen again with each new application

Comment: i get windows 8.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows this will happen anytime u try to use same port, which was not released earlier

Comment: I tried to delete the cache and remove the modules and the installation of npm but it doesn't work
And this is not the host ...
Another idea?

Answer (score 27):

Add **C:\Windows\System32** to the global PATH environment variable.

Comment: This saved my day after running npx create-react-app 6 times reading other answers.

Comment: What if I get this error on a Mac?

Comment: @ArianaRubí Have you tried closing and re-opening the terminal?

Answer (score 15):

**Solution 1**

Set your environment variable to C:\Windows\System32 . This works for me.

[Sets System variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqYmM.jpg)

**Solution 2**

---

If the first one doesn't work follow the 2nd steps. Navigate to your project folder and type this command >>>

```
rm -rf node_modules

rm package-lock.json

rm  yarn.lock

npm cache clear --force

npm install
```

**Solution 3**

Downgrade react-scripts in package.json file

Comment: New: npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 6):

For all those Who've come to this problem from react scripts not starting. The solution is

1. Go to search bar and write **environment variables**. You should see an option to called **edit system environment variables** or something similar.
2. Under the Advanced section there is a enivronment variable button. click it.
3. After that you will see an option named **path** click on it.
4. click add button and add following directory `C:\Windows\System32`.
5. close down your editor and restart your command terminal.
   Problem should be resolved now

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after I tried to install Mongo DB. I found out that this problem only exists with react-scripts@3.0.0. Try to reinstall your npm with a different react script version. Simply go to your folder in command and reinstall like this:

```
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

After that the app worked for me again.

Answer (score 1):

If someone hits this coming from Angular 2+, remove the --open from ng serve or run without this option.