# Why npm start is getting error for react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I'm trying to start a React application, with npm but I get this error:

```
      events.js:174
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

     Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
          at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
          at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    Emitted 'error' event at:
          at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
          at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I'm using node version 10.16.3 and npm 6.13.6. I've cleaned npm cache and install npm again, but I'm getting always the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with npm start (error : spawn cmd ENOENT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054403/problem-with-npm-start-error-spawn-cmd-enoent)

Comment: Looks like you're trying to spawn `cmd`, which doens't exist. `cmd.bat`, however, does.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing these three steps:

1. `npm install -g npm@latest` to update npm because it is sometimes buggy.
2. `rm -rf node_modules` to remove the existing modules.
3. `npm install` to re-install the project dependencies.

Comment: Hey Anil, please always read the question, in this case the OP has already done so, read _I've cleaned npm cache and install npm again_

Answer (score 0):

the problem is fixed , i've installed another version of "react-scripts" , because the actuel version is not stable , so i use to overwrite it with the given version, so use this command to install :

```
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
```

Once the installation is completed your can run your reac app :

```
npm start
```