# react error-error: This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

In my project, I'm using react. Now what I'm trying to do is deploy my project which is in remote server into the actual server. I'm using npm to create and start a project. But I can't build my project since the following error occurs again and again,

```
C:\Users\User\react-tutorial>npm start

> react-tutorial@0.1.0 start C:\Users\User\react-tutorial
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.225.236/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\User\react-tutorial\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-tutorial@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-tutorial@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-27T07_26_30_467Z-debug.log
```

How can I resolve this problem?

edit:it worked i got the answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with npm start (error : spawn cmd ENOENT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054403/problem-with-npm-start-error-spawn-cmd-enoent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054403/problem-with-npm-start-error-spawn-cmd-enoent)

Try to add C:\Windows\System32 to the global PATH environment variable or clear npm cache with

```
npm cache clear --force
```