# Unable to run expo developer tools

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I am  getting an error when I start run the scaffolded react native program using the command NPM start .Error is

```
C:\Users\ron\Desktop\pro\DoneWithIt>npm start

> @ start C:\Users\ron\Desktop\pro\DoneWithIt
> expo start

Starting project at C:\Users\ron\Desktop\pro\DoneWithIt
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ron\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-27T14_46_27_490Z-debug.log
```

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054403/problem-with-npm-start-error-spawn-cmd-enoent might help

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have not set "%SystemRoot%\system32" to path variable in environment variables.