# how to run my node application and react app in the same time with one command?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am going to build my boilerplate for React and node, the root folder structure is look like this

```
    - (root level)
    - client - src
             - public
             - package.json
             - ... 

    - package.json
    - server.js
    - node_modules
```

In my package.json of root folder, I have some code like:

```
 "start": " nodemon ./server.js | react-scripts start ./client"
```

When I run `npm start`, only the react app is build and run, the node app doesn't run. Any tips for how to just run `npm start` and both React and node app run?

By the way, I have set `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"` in the client's package.json. The server.js has code like

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// console.log that your server is up and running
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Thank you.

---

**Solution:**

Thanks so much for rodrigoap replies.

I use the [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) package to solve my problem.

My `package.json` in my root folder look like this and work:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "concurrently \"cd client && npm run start\" \"npm run start\"",
    "start": "nodemon ./server.js"
  },
```

Comment: Would any of these solutions work? https://itnext.io/4-solutions-to-run-multiple-node-js-or-npm-commands-simultaneously-9edaa6215a93

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Comment: your solutions is really helpful, I will try to fix it by reading them first and will update my solutions later, thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

I found  2 ways to do it

1 by command

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "(cd server && npm run start) & npm run start"
  }
```

2 by npm package

- concurrently [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)
- npm-run-all [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all)