# Chaining package.json scripts to start Express server and Vue app

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, npm, npm-scripts

I have built an app using Vue.js and express.js.  Currently I have to open two terminal windows and run `npm run serve` in one and `npm start` in the other. I want to make the server run after the Vue.js app builds in the same terminal. I read on this [article](https://itnext.io/4-solutions-to-run-multiple-node-js-or-npm-commands-simultaneously-9edaa6215a93) that I can get both scripts to run by chaining the two `package.json` scripts together, but for the life of me can't figure out how.  My project is structured as such:

```
├── project
├── _frontend
|   ├── package.json
├── backend
|   ├── package.json
```

I have tried the following ways:

```
1st try - "serve": "vue-cli-service serve && (cd ../server && npm start)"
2nd try - "serve": "vue-cli-service serve && (cd ../server && npm run start)"
3rd try - "serve": "vue-cli-service serve && (cd ../server) && npm start"
```

The Vue.js app builds and runs just fine but the server does not start. I tried doing the reverse on the server `package.json` as well and the server starts but the app does not build. Is this something I can not accomplish due to the folder setup or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&&` executes commands in series. `vue-cli-service serve && cd ../server && npm start` won't work as expected because the script stops at `vue-cli-service serve` until the server is shut down.

For cross-platform script, [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) or other similar packages can be used to execute commands in parallel:

```
"serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
"start": "concurrently \"npm run serve\" \"cd ../server && npm start\""
```

Comment: This couldn't have come at a better time.  Wonderful, thanks!