# Typescript build in watch mode with eslint possible?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Is there a way doing this without webpack or other bundlers?

Or the only option is to use two consoles where in one you will build and in second lint?

Comment: What are you using to do your build? webpack?

Comment: @NicholasTower typescript by command tsc -w

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no way around the fact that this will require two processes:  one for 'tsc -w' and the other for the linting.  The linting can happen in a 2nd terminal, in your IDE, or in your build script, but either way it is still another process.

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

For instance,
first: `npm i tsc-watch -D`
and then, in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
   "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
   "serve:reload": "npm run lint && node ./dist/index.js",
   "serve": "tsc-watch --noClear --onSuccess \"npm run serve:reload\"",
```