# How to run node server.js and npm start with one command

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I spun up a new create-react-app and an Express backend locally. Right now I have to run `node server.js` and `npm start` separately to make sure both the frontend and backend runs.

Is there a way that I can run both with just one npm command by just editing my package.json file?

Comment: Is it an option to just create a batch/shell file of some kind and execute both commands?

Comment: I am not sure if it works with react too, but have you looked at https://nodemon.io/?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Comment: I would recomend this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Answer (score 7):

This is how I do it using a module named [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

1. Install concurrently using npm.
2. Add the script to the package.json file of the root folder.

   "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "start": "node index.js",
       "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
       "server": "nodemon index.js",
       "dev": "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\""
       }

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Under your package.json file you can use:

```
{
  "name": "projectX",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev:api": "node server.js",
    "dev:client": "npm start",
    "dev": "npm run dev:api && npm run dev:client"
  }
}
```

If you run `npm run dev` it will run both of your scripts.

But I wouldn't recommend this approach because you are making your backend & frontend dependent on each other. That means you will have one version for both, one CI/CD pipeline, one deployment.

I would have two separate projects.

Comment: can we do something like cd backend && npm start, if we want to maintain only one package.json file?

Comment: @RohanDevaki Yes, you can of course. The best solution would be using docker containers.

Comment: i dont know about docker containers, i am still learnig them, i will check it , thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In your `package.json` add another script

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "..."
    "start-server": "node server.js && npm start",
  }
```

Comment: Should also point out that `start-server` needs to be run using `$ npm run start-server` instead of `$ npm start-server`.

Comment: Thanks so much. What if I want the command to be npm start instead of npm start-server?

Comment: You can just over ride the start command and write your own command `"start": "YOUR COMMAND"`

Comment: Well said @DibakarHalder

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file just add this script. There is no need for an npm package. However, if you need one concurrently will do the trick.

```
"scripts": {
        "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
        "server": "npm run watch --prefix server",
        "watch": "npm run server & npm run client",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
```