# npm start in React

Tags: reactjs, json-server

how can I start both this only by typing npm start?

```
"scripts"{
    "server": "json-server --watch appointmentList.json",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
}
```

what i've been doing was running each of them in different terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Answer (score 5):

you can install [`concurrently`](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently) to run the scripts in parallel, like this:

```
{
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm start\""
}
```

Comment: no problem. would be glad if you can accept it as an answer for posterity sake.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can append the desired commands to the `start` script:

```
"scripts": { 
    "server": "json-server --watch appointmentList.json", 
    "start": "json-server --watch appointmentList.json && react-scripts start"
}
```

and call it with `$npm run start` or `$npm start`

Answer (score 1):

You could use '&&' like:

```
{
    "server": "json-server --watch appointmentList.json", 
    "start": "npm run server && react-scripts start"
}
```

Comment: i tried this before but its not working. my server server runs in 3000, and my react app runs at 3001. so Im doing it on different terminal