# How to run react app aside using npm run build, npm run export, npm run serve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-boilerplate

I currently have app that uses react boilerplate, My question is, is there any other to run it aside from using:

npm run build 
npm run export
npm run serve

Every time i change something from the code, i have to do the above procedure which is time consuming.

Thanks

Comment: In the [documentation](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/docs/general/commands.md) it says to run `npm run start` which will start a dev server which will do incremental builds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Comment: As Jacob Smit said, `npm run start` will start a dev server that will watch your files for changes and automatically update.

Comment: hmm.. the npm run start didn't work..

Comment: Can you attach the contents of your package.json (at least the scripts section) so we can see what has been attached by the boiler plate you are using?

Comment: `npm install` first... maybe...