# How to use Antdesign and Tailwindcss in react together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, tailwind-css

to use TailwindCss, we need craco, so the script should be

```
    "start": "craco start ",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

to use antDesign-mobile, the script should be

```
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

How to run both at the same time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Comment: it's possible but there are some questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68924385/using-antdesign-with-tailwindcss-in-a-react-project