# Multiple cli command in single line angular

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

Want to run multiple command in angular which will be executed one after another. like ng serve, ng bulid in sequencewise.

Answer (score 3):

You could write additional script entries to combine commands.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "My Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "tbuild": "ng test && ng build",       // <-- test and build sequentially
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

You could then run the script entry from the project root folder like

```sh
npm run tbuild
```

To run the commands in parallel see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30950032/6513921).

Comment: Hi @Michael D, I tried to apply above script, but only one command in running i.e. ng test, ng build is not working in sequence, please check

Comment: Did `ng test` complete? You could also try `"tbuild": "npm run test && npm run build"`.

Comment: yes, ng test is complete, it is showing Total success test cases after that nothing is happening

Comment: Ok,  Thanks @Michael D,