# Best way to run asynchronous code during a webpack build?

Tags: webpack

During my build, I need to download files over HTTP, process them, and finally save them as part of the resulting bundle (I'm not writing a reusable plugin, so saving to hardcoded paths that I know to be the build's output location is fine).

Currently I'm doing it before exporting the config:

```js
fetchFilesFromInternetAndProcessThem().then(
  () => console.info("Successfully fetched, processed & included external files in the build."),
  e => console.error("Failed to include external files in the build.", e)
);

module.exports = {
  target: "node",
  stats: "minimal",
  ...
```

However, if the promise fails, the build will obviously still succeed... which is *bad* because those files are required for the successful running of my application.

**Is there a plugin I can use (or other solution)** that
allows arbitrary asynchronous code execution before/after a build, and will fail the build if said asynchronous code fails?

Comment: Do you need to feed that downloaded files to webpack or e.g. you just need to download them and copy to some output dir?

Comment: Download the file, process it using custom code (basically converting the downloaded JWK to a PEM), then copy to output dir. Webpack does not need them for anything it's doing.

Comment: then u can just start 2 simultaneous processes - webpack build + your download, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel

Answer (score 0):

I created my own plugin in the end.

If `myFunc` throws an error, then the build fails, which is what I want:

```js
class RunPromiseWebpackPlugin {
  asyncHook;
  constructor(asyncHook) {
    this.asyncHook = asyncHook;
  }

  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.beforeCompile.tapPromise("RunPromiseWebpackPlugin", this.asyncHook);
  }
}


async function myFunc() {
  // Does asynchronous stuff.
}

module.exports = {
  target: "node",
  stats: "minimal",
  plugins: [
    new RunPromiseWebpackPlugin(myFunc),
  ],
  ...
}
```