# Running npm concurrently

Tags: node.js

I have been referencing this post: [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

However, neither of my apps launch with `npm run dev`. Both apps exit with code 1.

My package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve",
  "start:lt": "ng serve --configuration=lt",
  "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm start\" \"npm start:lt\""
}
```

And yes, I have concurrently installed.

Comment: npm _run_ start:lt?

Comment: Ofcourse, how did I not see that. How do I also add in a  port to run start:lt? Doing `npm run start:lt -p 4201` doesnt seem to work

Comment: Maybe `-- -p 4210`, you usually need `--` to indicate that the other arguments go to the script not `npm` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/foreman module to start app.

first, you need `Procfile` with commands, you plan to execute in parallel

```
start: ng serve
start_lt: ng serve --configuration=lt
```

second, add it to package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start":"nf start"
}
```

third - define PORT variable in `.env` file

```
PORT=4201
```

and, finaly, you can start your applicaiton by `npm start` - it will start `foreman` executable, that starts both `start` and `start_lt` components in parallel