# How to use environment variables with static JS in public folder

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have **VueJS** app (`Vue CLI 3`) and additional **static JS script** in `public` folder. And I don't understand how I can use `.env` in this `.js`.

Let's say I have some specific environment variable, for example `MY_URL` and my JS file:

```js
const myUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_MY_URL;
```

And it's not working, because static files from `public` folder don't processed by webpack as I understand.

Maybe someone knows good solution? Or maybe other solutions\workarounds?

In my case, I put `.js` to `src` and add new `entry` by `chainWebpack`:

```js
config.entryPoints.delete('app')

config.entry('app')
    .add('./src/main.ts')
    .end()
    .entry('myScript')
    .add('./src/myScript.js')
    .end()
```

And now webpack build the script as separate file, but injects to `index.html` with `app.js`. This is not what I really want.

So, main purpose - build separate static JS file with specific name without hash (for example, `myScript.js`) which would contain variable from `.env` (`.env.production`, `.env.development`)

Comment: Can you just store two versions of the env variable? One in `.env` and one in your actual environment? in .js files use `process.env.MY_ENV` in .vue files use `process.env.VUE_APP_MY_URL;`

Comment: @JesseRezaKhorasanee yes, I can, but It won't work because `process` variable is not available in static JS files in `public` folder (`ReferenceError: process is not defined`).

In `index.html` we can use `BASE_URL` (`<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">`). Maybe there is the same for static JS?

Hopefully I don't need to write my own JS-loader for this.

Comment: I see. Can I ask why you need environment variables in the public folder? Without node, there is not a way to access environment variables as far as I know.

Comment: I think this thread should give you a solution:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/environment-variables-inside-files-js-under-public-folder/40322

Comment: I need env. variable in public folder because my static script contains functions and classes for iFrame (external usage by other sites). And I need to change URLs depending on environment (production, development).

Comment: So, in file I would have `const myUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_MY_URL;`
After build for production: `const myUrl ='https://www.production.com';`
After build for development: `const myUrl ='https://www.development.com';`

And it's not only variable for `base_url`, also I have 3rd party URLs (sandboxes for development, and production APIs for production)

Comment: Solution in your link looks same as mine with moving script to `src` and adding new `entry`, but my script start to inject to `index.html`, because webpack decides that my script for iFrame (script for external usage) - other entry point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main fact about static files in `public` folder from [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling):

> Static assets placed in the **public** directory will **simply be copied** and **not go through webpack**

So, I cannot use `.env` with static files in `public`.

I haven't found a perfect solution, but at least 3 acceptable options:

---

1. **JS file as entry**, as [Jesse Reza Khorasanee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2217801/jesse-reza-khorasanee) said in comments and gave a [link](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/environment-variables-inside-files-js-under-public-folder/40322) to almost same question

*The main idea:*
configure `vue.config.js` for an additional entry and force webpack to process my file.

```js
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    entry: {
      public: "./public/main.js"
    },
    output: {
      filename: "[name]/[name].main.js"
    }
  }
};
```

This solution would work with certain features:

- at least **two entry points**: **main entry** for my SPA (`main.js`) and **additional entry** just for my static JS.
  It's not good, because processed JS would contain a link to `vendors.js` chunk as one of the entries. But I need JS file processed by webpack only.
- same `output.filename` and `hash` in filename with **clear config** (it's not work, because I use this script as 3rd party JS and load by static name), or different `output.filename` for my JS file but with **dirty config**:

```js
configureWebpack: config => {
        config.output.filename = (pathData) => {
            return pathData.chunk.name === 'myScript'
                ? '[name].js' : '[name].[hash].js';
        };
    ...
}
```

- If I leave my JS in `public` folder I get two files after build: one in default `js` folder with other static assets and another in root folder near `main.js`

---

2. **[Multi-Page Application](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#building-a-multi-page-app)** (configuration for [Vue multi-page mode](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages))

```js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      // entry for the page
      entry: 'src/index/main.js',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
    },
    // when using the entry-only string format,
    // template is inferred to be `public/myScript.html`
    // and falls back to `public/index.html` if not found.
    // Output filename is inferred to be `myScript.html`.
    myScript: 'src/myScript.js'
  }
}
```

This solution would work almost like the first solution and I get a clear config file. But still I have problem with `vendors.js` seems like `pages` option work directly with `html-webpack-plugin` and I can config `chunks` which would load with my `page`, and I tried different ways to setup this option but without success. Vendors is still part of `myScript` entry.

---

3. **Build JS file as [library](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library)**

I chose this solution in my case. Because it's clear and short.

I put additional script to my `package.json`: `vue-cli-service build --no-clean --target lib --name paysendPaymentLibrary src/payment.js` and change main `build` script.

Final version of `package.json`:

```js
...
"scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build && npm run build-library",
    "build-library": "vue-cli-service build --no-clean --target lib --name myScriptLibrary src/myScript.js"
  },
...
```

After run `npm run build` I get static files for SPA and three files for my script:

- `myScriptLibrary.umd.min.js`
- `myScriptLibrary.umd.js`
- `myScriptLibrary.common.js`

For 3rd party site I use `myScriptLibrary.umd.js` file.

If you choose this solution **be careful** when you build your application, because:

- in **Windows** `vue-cli-service build & npm run build-library` scripts would run **sequentially**, but in **Unix** it runs **in parallel**. It can cause deletion of your SPA files. So be sure to use `&&` instead of `&` (see [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)  about environments and parallel\sequential script running)
- **size** of processed files would be **bigger than raw** static JS. For example, in my case raw file size: `4 KiB`, after build: `15.44 KiB`, gzipped: `5.78 KiB`.