# How to have 2 postbuild scripts in next.js package.json

Tags: next.js

I have multiple postbuild scripts inside on my Next.js project package.json file.

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "postbuild": "node ./src/scripts/build-algolia-search.js",
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

I am getting a Duplicate object key warning. Will this work? If not, how can I add both of the scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of researching I found this: [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Basically you can add `&&` or `&` to run them sequentially or in parallel (in that order). For my example:

```json
"postbuild": "next-sitemap & node ./src/scripts/build-algolia-search.js",
```