# npm parallel execution of commands not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a package.json file at the root of my project folder which contains client and server folders.
in the root package.json I have the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "npm run watch --prefix server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "watch": "npm run server & npm run client"
  }
```

but when i try to run `npm run watch` only the `server` script runs, what I don't understand is if I paste the contents of the watch script into the terminal it works just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, it does not.

Comment: Why not? It shows alternatives.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the problem is If I paste the command in the `watch` script into the terminal it works, but when I do `npm run watch` it does not work (it only starts the `server`).

Answer (score 1):

`npm run <script>` uses `cmd.exe` by default if you are on `windows`, and cmd does not support `&` to run commands in parallel, so it is better to use a package like `npm-run-all`.