# How can I run other commands on top of nodemon

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, npx

I was just woundering if it possible to run other commands along side nodemon package?

What I am trying to achieve here?

In `package.json`:
I have two scripts `nodemon` and `npx` for tailwind css

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js",
    "dev": "nodemon main.js && npx tailwindcss -i ./input.css -o ./output.css --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
 }
```

I'm trying to run both packages at the same time so I tried to add the `&&` btween the first and the second command but that didn't work, because both nodemon and tailwind css keep listing for file changes without exiting.

I'm trying to make them both some how run at the same same time.

is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` only runs commands after each other. Not concurrently

You can use a package like [concurrently](http://npmjs.org/package/concurrently) to run them in parallel.

`"dev": "concurrently \"nodemon main.js\" \"npx tailwindcss -i ./input.css -o ./output.css --watch\"`

There are also alternatives to concurrently

Answer (score 1):

You can use a package called concurrently.

```
npm i concurrently --save-dev
```

and then your script should look like this:

```
"dev": "concurrently \"nodemon main.js\" \"npx tailwindcss -i ./input.css -o ./output.css --watch\" "
```

You can find more details in the link below

[How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)