# How can I run nodemon and tailwind at the same time?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, tailwind-css

When building node projects I have my start script which is:

```
"start": "nodemon app.js"
```

and my tailwind script to run the build process:

```
"tailwind:css": "postcss public/styles/tailwind.css -o public/styles/style.css"
```

is there any way I can have my nodemon running watching for changes as well as my tailwindcss watching for changes.

I seem to have to stop the nodemon server and then run the tailwind command to rebuild, then start the nodemon server back up to look at the changes I made.
I am new to tailwind so I am not sure but there has to be a better approach to this. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Answer (score 0):

You can launch both with your "npm run start" command like this:

```
"scripts": {

"nodemon": "nodemon app.js",
"tailwind": "postcss tailwind.css -o style.css",
"start": "npm run tailwind && npm run nodemon"
```

In addition, you can run first Tailwind for changes and then run nodemon with the package npm-run-all:

https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/watch-tailwind-changes-update-browser-sync/

Answer (score -1):

`"tailwind:css": "postcss public/styles/tailwind.css -o public/styles/style.css --watch"`