# Laravel artisan serve and npm run dev single command

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, vite

Is there a way to run terminal commands simultaneously

Like
`php artisan serve`

And
`npm run dev` (for laravel vite)

Run it in a comment or terminal with a shortcut

Comment: You can define a composer script that do both : `"serve": ["npm run dev", "php artisan serve"]` and then `composer serve` it will run both commands one after another. You can also use npm scripts instead, it's the same thing, like `npm run serve`, the only difference is that it's a string not an array ; `"serve": "npm run dev && php artisan serve"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Comment: @Lk77 unless the first is a long running process, then the second won't run until the first exits cleanly.

Comment: @Matt that's intended, because we need to wait for build to finish before serving, if we do the other way around, we will have an error on laravel side stating that build files are missing

Comment: `run dev` is often a long running/server process that doesn't exit, more so in the `webpack`/`vite` case.  I was just noting that for that case, the problem requires a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is a creative way
You should define a variable in your command line
İf you're using linux run this command:

```
export part="php $PWD/artisan serve"
```

**Note**:`part` is variable name. Name it whatever you want (part stands for php artisan)

**Note**:by running this command the variable will accessible just in that CMD window. That means this way is a temporary way and **if you want to access it all the time you need to add this command to your `.bash` or `.profile` file**

Answer (score 3):

There is another solution using `concurrently` npm package

first install `concurrently` (you can install it globally)

```
npm i concurrently -g
```

then run

```
concurrently "php artisan serve" "npm run dev"
```

or you can use it as package.json script

1 : update you package json like this

```
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build ",
        "start": "concurrently  \"php artisan config:cache\" \"php artisan serve\" \"npm run dev \"  "
    },
```

2 : in terminal run `npm start`