# npm start json-server in background

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start, json-server

I'm trying to have my `npm start` script run `json-server` in the background in parallel to then running `react-scripts` to start UI. How would I go about doing this? I've tried various things with single & and prestart, etc but everything results in json-server starting to watch my db file but then react-scripts doesn't run.

The main 2 which I thought should do the trick are below, but neither work.

```
  "scripts": {
    "prestart" : "json-server --watch ../sample-db.json --port 3010 --delay 800&",
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start",
```

and

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "json-server --watch ../sample-db.json --port 3010 --delay 800&set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start",
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite a duplicate, but as indicated by @Max this has a few options:

[How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

So here's one way:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start",
  "mockserver": "json-server --watch ../sample-db.json --port 3010 --delay 800",
  "startdev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm start\" \"npm run mockserver\"",
}
```

And I see that on windows I need to use "start" which was why single ampersand wasn't working.