# Webpack 5 & Sass - index.css does not update with new content from main.css

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-5

## Summary:

My Webpack no longer converts css from `main.css` into `index.css` upon running the build script. I need help figuring this out.

### Background info:

I have a plain HTML/Sass website, and I'm attempting to push some CSS updates into production. When I updated to Webpack 5 in April 2023, everything worked fine (with some tweaks)¹. I could modify the code and see it reflected served at localhost.

As I understand it, Webpack converts the `.scss` code into `.css` code, and puts it into a `main.css` file within a `.gitignore`'d `/dist` directory. The web server then reads from the `main.css` file. This works fine and dandy in dev, but deploying into production no longer converts that code into an `index.css` file.

This worked in April, but now it does not do so, and I cannot figure out why. I've only made changes within my `index.html` and `index.scss` files, so the edit/test/deploy process should have remained unchanged.

I've tried searching forums for assistance, but most of those similar issues deal with versions of Webpack much older than v5, and those solutions have become deprecated.

Here's my Webpack:

```js
// Generated using webpack-cli https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production';

const stylesHandler = MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader;

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  // disabling cache in watch mode 
  cache: false,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    assetModuleFilename: 'public/[name][ext]',
  },
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    host: 'localhost',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html',
    }),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: "html-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [stylesHandler,'css-loader'],
        sideEffects: true,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [stylesHandler, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        sideEffects: true,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = () => {
  if (isProduction) {
    config.mode = 'production';
  } else {
    config.mode = 'development';
  }
  return config;
};
```

***¹** `MiniCssExtractPlugin` is required for sass to work properly & [`cache: false,`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/23#issuecomment-373939895) for `main.css` to get live updates in watch mode*

Here's my package.json:

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "JF Portfolio",
  "name": "jf-portfolio",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode=development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "serve": "webpack serve & compile:sass",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass -w styles/index.scss src/index.css --recursive"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.5",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.7",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.77.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.1"
  }
}
```

**My basic directory structure:**

- `/dist` (uncommited directory containing Webpack emitted files)

  - `/public` (all content stored top-level, no sub-directories)
  - `index.html`
  - `main.css` (webpack converts `index.scss` into css in this file)
  - `main.js`
- `/public` (contains content in sub-directories)

  - `/fonts`
  - `/images`
  - `/svg-icons`
  - `adocument.pdf`
  - `anotherdocument.pdf`
- `/src` (contains the final "converted" CSS file for import into HTML)

  - `index.css` (***this is the file that is no longer getting updated from `main.css`***)
  - `index.js`
- `/styles`

  - `index.scss` (this is where I make stylistic changes)
- `index.html`

When I initially set up this version of Webpack, updates from `index.scss` where pushed into `main.css` live (I think it's called hot-loading?). And when it came time to deploy, code from `main.css` was pushed into `index.css`. Basically:

```
index.scss --> main.css --> index.css
dev --> serve --> deploy
```

Essentially, `index.css` is supposed to be the "Okay I'm ready to go live with this" file, and it is the one which is imported in the `index.html`. However, updates are no longer making it from `main.css` into `index.css`.

dev ✅ --> serve ✅ --> deploy ❌

**Things I have attempted:**

- I have tried switching from production to development and back

  - `npm run build:prod` & `npm run build:dev`
- I've tried emptying out `index.css` to see if that will force a refill.
- I've tried deleting `index.css` altogether to see if a replacement will get generated.
- I have deleted and reinstalled my `/node_modules`.
- I have read and reread Webpack docs
- I have searched StackOverlow and GitHub, and the only thing that's close is a [GH workaround related to hot-loading(?) in dev](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/23#issuecomment-373939895), but does not touch on getting updates into the production file.

At the moment, my only recourse is to manually copy the code from `main.css` into `index.css` and then fix all the imports/references so they use the correct paths (remember, webpack emits it all into `/dist/public` with no further sub-directories).

I need help! Please and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe I found a solution, and it's quite silly. There was an error somewhere along the way with the script which wasn't logged out anywhere obviously in the terminal where the `compile:sass` script either wasn't running, or there was something else that conflicted with its operation. Live updates on the screen weren't working, and changes saved to `index.scss` were not being transpiled into `index.css`.

I found a StackOverflow comment here about [running npm scripts concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30950298/21558165) using an appropriately named npm package: [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

With `concurrently` installed, I modified my `package.json` to be this for my serve command:

```json
// old
"serve": "webpack serve & compile:sass",

// new
"serve": "concurrently --kill-others \"webpack serve\" \"npm run compile:sass\"",
```

My `index.css` now receives streaming updates from any changes I make in my `index.scss` whenever the file is saved.