# Starting strongswan/charon from Docker

Tags: docker, strongswan

I am creating a docker image using strongswan, with the following inside the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y systemd strongswan libstrongswan strongswan-swanctl strongswan-charon charon-systemd; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt-lists/*;

RUN ipsec start
```

(docker-compose does add the NET_ADMIN capability)

However after starting, the instance only has `starter.charon.pid` in `/var/run` instead of the `charon.vici` that i am expecting. If I then run `ipsec start` inside the container, I obtain

```
Starting strongSwan 5.9.8 IPsec [starter]...
removing pidfile '/var/run/starter.charon.pid', process not running
```

And then everything seems to be working.

How can I automatize the startup of ipsec from the Dockerfile? I need strongswan to be activated to then use it from a python script.

I tried to change the docker command to `RUN ipsec stop && ipsec start` and variants to no avail.

Comment: You can never start background processes from a Dockerfile; the image only persists the filesystem and some related metadata.  You may not be able to run this setup in Docker at all, since the Docker environment usually fully manages the network setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze hmm, at least that explains why all the examples I saw on Github required manual action. From what you tell me it seems that the only possibility would be to create a wrapper around charon that runs charon and listens to external command from another container about which commands to run. Or I could also just use virtualbox instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

As mentioned in comments a Dockerfile cannot run a background process. However, there is always a foreground process (through `ENTRYPOINT`), which in my case was already used to run a flask server.

However, replacing that line with `ENTRYPOINT ['bash', 'run.sh']` and with the following bash file

```bash
ipsec start
echo 'waiting 2s for ipsec to start' && sleep 2 && chmod 777 /run/charon.vici && echo 'done'
flask --app app.py run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000 --debug
```

Then everything works as expected.

Using a supervisor such as [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23968289/6404901) is probably the next step to ensure services are automatically reloaded in case of a crash.