# How to extend an existing docker image?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I'm using [the official elasticsearch Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/elasticsearch/) instead of setting up my own elastic search instance. And that works great, up to the point when I wanted to extend it. I wanted to install [marvel](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/marvel/) into that ElasticSearch instance to get more information.

Now dockerfile/elasticsearch automatically runs ElasticSearch and setting the command to `/bin/bash` doesn't work, neither does attaching to the container or trying to access it over SSH, nor installing ssh-daemon with `apt-get install -y openssh-server`.

In this particular case, I could just go into the container's file system and execute `opt/elasticsearch/bint/plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest` and everything worked.

But how could I install an additional service which needs to be installed with `apt-get` when I can't have a terminal inside the running container?

Comment: The  [elasticsearch url](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/elasticsearch/) changed to [https://hub.docker.com/r/_/elasticsearch/](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/elasticsearch/)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Simply extend it using a Dockerfile that start with

```
FROM dockerfile/elasticsearch
```

and install marvel or ssh-server or whatever you need. Then, end with the correct command to start your services. You can use supervisor to start multple services, see [Run a service automatically in a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252356/run-a-service-automatically-in-a-docker-container/19273735#19273735) for more info on that.

Comment: Is there a way to extend a Dockerfile, as opposed to an image ?

Say I have a Dockerfile for an email server. It stores files in various ways (Amazon S3, CEPH, etc) so I need a library for each of those services. I would like to have a base Dockerfile for the server and then one Dockerfile per service used to store the files. All of this without having to worry about intermediate images.

Comment: nope. In this case a tactic can be one Dockerfile with as much shared functionality as you can put in it, and an array of small Dockerfile extending on newly build image that installs your library for the specific service

Comment: @qkrijger - Thanks for starting me off on the right road - I have provided a fully working Dockerfile in my recent answer.

Comment: What if the image you are extending already has an entry point defined?   Can you still have another entry point when extending?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using *docker-compose*, what I usually do is to add a first section for the base image you plan to reuse, and then use that image as the base in the rest of the services' *Dockerfiles*, something along the lines of:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
    base:
        build: ./images/base

    collector:
         build: ./images/collector
```

Then, in images/collector/Dockerfile, and since my project is called *webtrack*, I'd type

```
FROM webtrack_base
...
```

And now it's done!

Answer (score 1):

**Update August 2016**

Having found very little current information on how to do this with latest versions of ElasticSearch (2.3.5 for example), Kibana (4.5.3) and Marvel & Sense plugins, I opted to take the steeper path and write my own image.

Please find the source code (Dockerfile) and README [here](https://github.com/tawawa/elasticsearch-kibana-marvel-sense)

```
FROM java:jre-alpine

MAINTAINER arcseldon <arcseldon@gmail.com>

ENV ES_VERSION=2.3.5 \
    KIBANA_VERSION=4.5.3

RUN apk add --quiet --no-progress --no-cache nodejs \
  && adduser -D elasticsearch

USER elasticsearch

WORKDIR /home/elasticsearch

RUN wget -q -O - http://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/distribution/tar/elasticsearch/${ES_VERSION}/elasticsearch-${ES_VERSION}.tar.gz \
 |  tar -zx \
 && mv elasticsearch-${ES_VERSION} elasticsearch \
 && wget -q -O - http://download.elastic.co/kibana/kibana/kibana-${KIBANA_VERSION}-linux-x64.tar.gz \
 |  tar -zx \
 && mv kibana-${KIBANA_VERSION}-linux-x64 kibana \
 && rm -f kibana/node/bin/node kibana/node/bin/npm \
 && ln -s $(which node) kibana/node/bin/node \
 && ln -s $(which npm) kibana/node/bin/npm \
 && ./elasticsearch/bin/plugin install license \
 && ./elasticsearch/bin/plugin install marvel-agent \
 && ./kibana/bin/kibana plugin --install elasticsearch/marvel/latest \
 && ./kibana/bin/kibana plugin --install elastic/sense 

CMD elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch --es.logger.level=OFF --network.host=0.0.0.0 & kibana/bin/kibana -Q

EXPOSE 9200 5601
```

If you just want the pre-built image then please do:

```
docker pull arcseldon/elasticsearch-kibana-marvel-sense
```

You can visit the repository on hub.docker.com [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/arcseldon/elasticsearch-kibana-marvel-sense/)

Usage:

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 5601:5601 arcseldon/elasticsearch-kibana-marvel-sense
```

You can connect to Elasticsearch with http://localhost:9200 and its Kibana front-end with http://localhost:5601.

You can connect to Marvel with http://localhost:5601/app/marvel and Sense with http://localhost:5601/app/sense

Hope this helps others and saves some time!