# Extending an existing Docker Image on Docker Hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm new to Docker and trying to get my head around extending existing Images.

I understand you can extend an existing Docker image using the FROM command in a Dockerfile (e.g. [How to extend an existing docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905803/how-to-extend-an-existing-docker-image)), but my question is -- in general, how can I install additional software / packages without knowing what the base operating system is of the base image or which package manager is available?

Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to run the base image you want to start `FROM` (perhaps using `docker exec`) and see what package managers are available (if any). Then you can write your `Dockerfile` with the correct software installation procedure.

Think of it the same way you'd add software to any computer: you'd either log into it yourself and poke around, or write an installation program that can handle all of the expected variations.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the source Dockerfile is provided and you can walk the chain backwards and gain a better understanding as you do.

For example, if we look at [the official Redis image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/redis/) we see the information tab says

> ## Supported tags and respective Dockerfile links
>
> - [2.6.17, 2.6 (2.6/Dockerfile)](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/062335e0a8d20cab2041f25dfff2fbaf58544471/2.6/Dockerfile)
> - [2.8.19, 2.8, 2, latest (2.8/Dockerfile)](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/062335e0a8d20cab2041f25dfff2fbaf58544471/2.8/Dockerfile)

So if you're interested in building off `redis:latest` you'd follow the second link and see that it in turn is built off of [`debian:wheezy`](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/debian/).

Most user-created images will either include their Dockerfile on the hub page or from a link there.

Comment: Unfortunately most of the images I'm looking at on Docker Hub don't have a Docker file, which lead to this question.

Comment: @MarcoBenvoglio I would avoid images without an associated Dockerfile - it's a bad sign.