# How to extend existing docker container?

Tags: docker

The tensorflow docker container is available at https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/ to extend this container with additional libraries such as `requests` I'm aware of two options.

1. Run the container and run `pip install requests`
2. Append `pip install requests` to the `dockerFile` that builds this container

Is there an alternative option ? Something like creating the `tensorflow/tensorflow` container from a dockerFile and then installing `requests` on this container.

Reading [How to extend an existing docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905803/how-to-extend-an-existing-docker-image) to accomplish this create a dockerFile with these contents ? :

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow
RUN pip install requests
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your original assertion is correct, create a new Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow
RUN pip install requests
```

now build it (note that the name should be lower case):

```
docker build -t me/mytensorflow .
```

run it:

```
docker run -it me/mytensorflow
```

execute a shell in it (`docker ps -ql` gives us an id of the last container to run):

```
docker exec -it `docker ps -ql` /bin/bash
```

get logs from it:

```
docker logs `docker ps -ql`
```

The ability to extend other images is what makes docker really powerful, in addition you can go look at their Dockerfile:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/docker

and start from there as well without extending their docker image, this is a best practice for people using docker in production so you know everything is built in-house and not by some hacker sneaking stuff into your infrastructure.  Cheers! and happy building

Answer (score 3):

you could enter the running container via:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bin/bash
```

or if a name is set:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME bin/bash
```