# I want to run a docker-compose.yml on a remote docker daemon, what about volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run `docker-compose up` on a remote docker daemon:

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://...:2375 docker-compose up
```

In `docker-compose.yml`, I have a volume binding to a local file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

This won't work, as the remote docker daemon will be unable to locate `./etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

What is the best approach to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend the existing docker image by creating your own docker image.
Ref : [How to extend existing docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830688/how-to-extend-existing-docker-container)

Copy the relevant files (from docker build-context) to appropriate directory and then it will be available in docker image and hence will also be available in remote docker demon as well.