# How can i construct a Docker for a Django Web App + Java?

Tags: django, docker

I have a web app developed with Django and some libraries are written in Java. (For ex : Stanford POS Tagger). I would like to know what can i do to dockerize my app. I find many tutorials about how to dockerize a Django App, but i don't know how to do it if some libraries need to use the JVM.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the base Django base image and extend it by installing the needed libraries. This is a very common practice in the ecosystem.

What commands to run really depend on what need to be installed. If you need reference, you can see how Java is installed in the upstream Java image: https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/e6e9cf8b21516ba764189916d35be57486203c95/8-jdk/Dockerfile

Other references:

- [How to extend existing docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830688/how-to-extend-existing-docker-container)
- https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#dockerfile-instructions

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much leodotcloud.