# return from docker-compose up in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-compose

I have base image with Jboss copied on it. Jboss is started with a script and takes around 2 minutes.
In my `Dockerfile` I have created a command.

```
CMD start_deploy.sh && tail -F server.log
```

I do a tail to keep the container alive otherwise "`docker-compose up`" exits when script finishes and container stops.

The problem is when I do "`docker-compose up`" through Jenkins the build doesn't finishes because of tail and I couldn't start the next build.

If I do "`docker-compose up -d`" then next build starts too early and starts executing tests against the container which hasn't started yet.

Is there a way to return from docker-compose up when server has started completely.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have chained commands or piped commands (`|`), it is easier to:

- easier wrap them in a script, and use that script in your `CMD` directive:

  ```
  CMD myscript
  ```
- or wrap them in an `sh -c` command:

  ```
  sh -c 'start_deploy.sh && tail -F server.log'
  ```

(but that last one depends on the `ENTRYPOINT` of the image.
A default `ENTRYPOINT` should allow this `CMD` to work)

Comment: Do you mean that if I wrap them in separate script & use that script in CMD, I would be able to return from docker-compose up when both scripts are executed ?

Comment: @ManishKumarThakur yes, that is the idea.

Comment: I'll try that. Would let you know. Thanks.

Comment: That didn't help. Result is same. I created a script startConatiner.sh & put the two commands in there. docker-compose starts the tailing and didn't return.

Comment: @ManishKumarThakur would it return without the tailing?

Comment: Without tailing it would return & container will exit.

Comment: @ManishKumarThakur So isn't it expected for the command to *not* return then? (since, if it was returning, the container would exit)

Comment: I want it to return but container should somehow run in background.

Comment: @ManishKumarThakur Then can you try and use a supervisord? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19273735/6309): it will prevent the container to exit early and monitor your processes

Comment: @ManishKumarThakur Or, simpler, run it in daemon: docker run -d. But in your case (docker-compose -d) that didn't work. So I would still use a supervisord.